# Cannot delete Numbers documents from iCloud Trash

Tags: icloud, trash

I am using Numbers and have saved some documents in iCloud. I am now trying to delete them. I moved them to the Trash and emptied the Trash.

Some time later, I see that these Numbers documents reappear in the Trash. I have tried:

- Manually deleting the files from Terminal
- Moving the files to the desktop and then deleting the items in the Trash.
- Deleting the documents from the ''recently deleted' section on my iPhone and iPad.

I am hesitant to disable/re-enable iCloud. but if that is what I must do then I will do it.

How can get these Numbers documents to be permanently deleted?